# Installing ansible 2.6 or older

Tags: apt-get

With 2.6.2, ansible started ignoring config files in world writable dirs, rendering many windows/vagrant setups useless. I try to install Ansible 2.6 or older.

System:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-132-generic x86_64)
```

The propvision.sh states

```
# Add Ansible Repository & Install Ansible
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ansible && sudo touch /root/ansible_ready
```

I adapted it to

```
 sudo apt-get install -y ansible=2.6.0 && sudo touch /root/ansible_ready
                                ^^^^^^
```

but that version was not found. How can I obtain 2.5 or 2.6? I am quite unexperienced with linux and the concept of installing something not by a doubleclick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For installation of Ansible version 2.6 on Trusty Tahr 14.04 (LTS), proceed with the follow commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
```

Add apt source list:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible-2.6.list << EOF
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-2.6/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible-2.6/ubuntu trusty main
EOF
```

Update apt and install Ansible:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y ansible
```

Comment: You can change the version and ubuntu codename to customize it for another versions of Ansible.